Lost context when iframe is removed from DOM
A button on the webpage triggers the removal of an iframe that I've currently switched to using switchFrame(). After that, the driver has lost all context of the page (e.g. driver.url returns null).
I've tried using switchPage() to select the window again, and tried switchFrame(null) to try pointing the driver back to the main content but still unable to interact with the elements/fetch URL.
Example:
* karate.log('Current URL:', driver.url) #Returns the expected URL
Then pressButton('Continue application')
And pauseSeconds(10)
* karate.log('Current URL:', driver.url) #Returns null


I'll be honest, the code for dealing with iframes is hard, I would strongly encourage you to dive into the karate code base and contribute a fix. If you can or if you can get some support from your org+team to do this, that is the best way forward.
